# Ubuntu 12.04 end of life support options

Tags: 12.04

Do I have any support options after Spring 2017 when Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin is set to end of life?  I have a client needing extended support.

Comment: I don't think so. Why not upgrade though?

Comment: I don't think Canonical offers 'past end of life' support.  Nor does this community, because the repos get retired and all security updates, etc. are halted for the release when it is EOL.  Upgrading to a supported release is about the only true-fire option you have to get 'ongoing support'.  Is there a reason you don't want to upgrade?